# Prove that if $x \in N_G(P)$, then $x \in P$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ and the order of $x \in G$ has order a power of $p$. Prove that if $x \in N_G(P)$, then $x \in P$.

Where do I begin on this proof?

Comment: You begin by observing that $\langle P,x \rangle$ is a $p$-group (i.e. its order is a power of $p$).

Comment: I know that $N_G(P)=\{ g \in G : gPg^{-1}=P \}$. So if $x \in N_G(P)$, then $x \in G$ such that $xPx^{-1}=P$?

Comment: Yes that's right. So $P \unlhd \langle P,x \rangle$. Deduce that $\langle P, x \rangle$ is a $p$-group.

Comment: Well it is a p-group because G has order p and we have xPx^{-1}=P. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ normalizes $P \in$ Syl$_p(G)$, that is $x \in N_G(P)$, then $H:=P\langle x \rangle$ is actually a subgroup of $G$. Also, $|H|=\frac{|P| \cdot |\langle x \rangle|}{|P \cap \langle x \rangle|}$, and this is a power of $p$, since $x$ is a $p$-element and $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup. But $P \subseteq H$, and by definition, $P$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$. It follows that $H=P\langle x \rangle=P$, whence $\langle x \rangle \subseteq P$. So $x \in P$.

There is another proof that uses Sylow theory in a different way: $P \unlhd N_G(P)$. If $x \in N_G(P)$ is a $p$-element, the $p$-subgroup $\langle x \rangle$ of $N_G(P)$ must be contained in some Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$. Since $P$ is the *only* Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$, it follows that $\langle x \rangle \subseteq P$.